# 404 Error Page not found. on Magento New Module on System, Configuration

Tags: php, magento

I created a new module which I will explain below. 
I can see the new options on the admin.
I clicked on role, administrators and saved.
I logged out and logged in

However I still see 404 Not found when I want to change the config.
http://screencast.com/t/IbLJeVjpxMm

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Luisvalencia_Affiliate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Luisvalencia_Affiliate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <luisvalencia_affiliate>
                <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Model</class>
            </luisvalencia_affiliate>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <affiliate>
                <class>Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper</class>
            </affiliate>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <luisvalencia_affiliate>
                        <class>luisvalencia_affiliate/observer</class>
                        <method>captureReferral</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </luisvalencia_affiliate>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <luisvalenciasection translate="title" module="affiliate">
                                        <title>Luisvalencia Section</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                    </luisvalenciasection>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <luisvalenciatab translate="label" module="affiliate">
            <label>Luisvalencia Cookie</label>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        </luisvalenciatab>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <luisvalenciasection  translate="label" module="affiliate">
            <label>Luisvalencia</label>
            <tab>luisvalenciatab</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <luisvalenciagroup translate="label">
                    <label>Luisvalencia Group</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <cookie_time translate="label">
                            <label>Set Cookie Time</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </cookie_time>
                    </fields>
                </luisvalenciagroup>
            </groups>
        </luisvalenciasection>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Data.php

```
<?php
class Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

Observer.php

```
<?php
class Luisvalencia_Affiliate_Model_Observer
{
    const COOKIE_KEY_SOURCE = 'luisvalencia_affiliate_source';

    public function captureReferral(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $cookietime = Mage::getStoreConfig('luisvalenciasection/luisvalenciagroup/cookie_time');
        if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('ref') != 'cj'){
            if( isset($_GET["ref"]) ){
                $ref=$_GET["ref"];
            }
            else{
                $ref='';
            }

            $name_c = 'ref';
            $val_c = $ref;
            $expired = 31556926; /* 1 year */
            $path = '/';

            $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
            $cookie->set($name_c, $val_c ,(int)$cookietime,$path);
        }
    }
}
```

Luisvalencia_Affiliate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Luisvalencia_Affiliate>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Luisvalencia_Affiliate>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Normally it is something with your session of login. Did you try to logout and login again? If that doesn't work, could you maybe give me more information about your changes?

Answer (score 0):

l.v

Add this code in config.xml

```
<resources>
    <affiliate_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Luisvalencia_Affiliate</module>
    </setup>
    <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
    </affiliate_setup>
    <affiliate_read>
    <connection>
        <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
    </affiliate_read>
    <affiliate_write>
    <connection>
        <use>core_write</use>
    </connection>
    </affiliate_write>
</resources>
```

after end of `</helpers>`

And then

```
create a installer:Luisvalencia/Affiliatesql/affiliate_setup/install-0.0.1.php
```

code:

```
<?php

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setReloadAclFlag(true);
$session->refreshAcl();
```

Answer (score 0):

none of the answers above was needed apparently, I was missing an acl section on adminhtml.xml

```
            <acl>
                <children>
                    <luisvalenciasection translate="title" module="affiliate">
                        <title>Luisvalencia Section</title>
                    </luisvalenciasection>
                </children>
            </acl>
```